# How to join two tables in Pig on some condition

Tags: apache-pig

I have two tables- Table A(Person_Name, Person_Salary), Table B(Person_Name, Store_shop) with a common column name Person_Name. I want to join these two tables on that common column but take only those rows for which salary>1000. I want to output list of stores for every individual whose salary is greater than 1000. Table B has list of stores where an individual shops meaning it has multiple rows for same person with different or repeating name of the stores he shop every time. 
I want to know how should I implement the condition of salary on the joining of tables

Comment: share what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

Load both datasets.Filter 1st dataset based on salary > 1000.Join the two datasets on person_name to get your output

```
A = LOAD 'dataA.txt' USING PigStorage(',') AS (name:chararray,salary:int);
B = LOAD 'dataB.txt' USING PigStorage(',') AS (name:chararray,store:int);
C = FILTER A BY (salary > 1000);
D = JOIN C BY name,B BY name;
E = FOREACH D GENERATE C.name,B.store;
DUMP E;
```

Comment: This one does not seem to work. Error log is showing Job failed, hadoop does not return any error message. There is some issue I think with the last line concerning relation E